# How to evaluate limit via the difference quotient and/or the Funda. Theorem of Calc?

Tags: calculus

Need help trying to evaluate this limit that is clearly related to the difference quotient and/or the Funda. Theorem of Calc (derivative of the integral is the function)

Anyone know how to close the deal here?  I am trying to translate what I have into the difference quotient so I can determine the f(x)

Am I barking up the right tree?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for you to understand and justify:

Define

$$F(x):=\int\limits_1^x (e^t+2)dt\implies F'(x)=e^x+2$$

and thus

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\int\limits_1^{1+h}(e^t+2)dt=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(1+h)-F(1)}h=:F'(1)=e+2\;\ldots$$

Comment: It seems to be I've a new antifan who's decided to downvote some  of my answers just like that...oh, well: these groupies can be tough.

Comment: This answer is probably the way the limit of the OP was "expected" to be solved, i.e. via the fundamental theorem of calculus applied first, and then the limit part shown equivalent to the derivative at $1$. For example if the integrand were $e^{t^2}+2$ rather than what it is, the approach the OP made (do the integral explicitly first) wouldn't work so easily. [+1 for an answer hinting to OP to see relation with fundamental theorem]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed to see in order to explicitly connect that first limit to the difference quotient format. – $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\int_x^{x+h} f(x)\, dx}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = F'(x) = f(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks right up to 
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{1+h}+2h-e}{h}.$$
This can be re-written as 
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{1+h}-e^1}{h}+2.$$
(where I mean the final $2$ included in the limit, but then the limit of 2 is just 2.)
Now the fraction part of the limit is the derivative definition of the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=1$. But the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, and you can finish.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I got it now.   How would you ever think of doing that?   It's harder to see when the x=1 is also in the mix.  If it were just $\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$ it would have been more obvious.

Comment: @JackOfAll Yes, many specific limits can be converted into derivatives, once the difference quotient of something is recognized. Of course there's always LHopital's rule if one is allowed to use it.